Errno 121: Remote I/O Error Problem. 'ADS 1x15'. After successful implementation of 2 Years
I am using ADS1X15 library to read analog data from ADC-1115 adc conver ter. I was successfully using this library as well as module for atleast 2 years.
Now the Python through the error [Errno 121] Remove I/O Error.
What could be the cause of this error?
def inductive_sensor():
    global close_application
    global indu_stop
    global peak_volt
    global valley_volt
    peak_volt = 0
    valley_volt = 10
    get_adc = False
    while True:
        try:
            ADS = ADS1x15.ADS1115(1, 0x48)
            ADS.setGain(ADS.PGA_2_048V)
            ADS.setDataRate(ADS.DR_ADS111X_860)
            break
        except:
            if close_application:
                break
    #print ('Inductive Sensor Running...')
    while not close_application:
        time.sleep(0.001)
        val_0 = ADS.readADC_Differential_0_1()
        volt = ADS.toVoltage(val_0)
        if volt > peak_volt :
            peak_volt = volt
        if volt < valley_volt :
            valley_volt = volt
        if maintenance :
            update_inductive(np.round(volt,3))
    indu_stop = True    
    #print ('Inductive Sensor Stopped...')  

I am getting this Error at the line val_0 = ADS.readADC_Differential_0_1()
When I run my program randomly this error would go. But, after a few minutes the error will be back.

See Tour to see how this site works
and How do I ask a good question?

We need to see the complete script.

Are you saying that absolutely nothing changed, and working code stopped working?
